# How to return multiple match with regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried this code:

```
/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g
```

to return multiple matches from text like this: some [[text]] and even [[more]] text. But instead of`text, more`, it only returns `text`. What I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FPeter how do you get the `match`?

Comment: @dawg There's nothing wrong with the regex.

Comment: Are you using `match()` or `exec()`? The latter only returns the first occurring match and requires a while loop to retrieve all matching groups.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is correct which includes the global match flag `/g`.

If you use the `match` method it should work fine.

```js
var stringToTest = "some [[text\]\] and even [[more]] text";
var regexToTest = /\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g;

var matches = stringToTest.match(regexToTest);
console.log(matches)
```

Comment: You posted answer to say *Your regex is correct*

Comment: It shows the match method also and the way it should work in JS.

Comment: How come the matches return the square brackets?  How would you modify this to _only_ return the contents between the normal braces (`.*?`)?

Answer (score 0):

The regex is ok:

```
var test = "[[text]] and even [[more]] text.".match(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g);
console.log(a);
> ["[[text]]", "[[more]]"]
```

Comment: You posted answer to say *regex is correct*

Answer (score 0):

Try to match the whole regular expression multiple times. Like this:
 /([[.*?]])+/g